# Unity 3D Camera Collision Detection

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I'm using the third person controller from invector and in the example scene, it has collision detection for the camera but it still goes through the wall a little. (You can see the other side of the wall.)Can someone point me into the right direction as to how to fix this?

```
     //Check if desired target position is not blocked       
if (CullingRayCast(desired_cPos, oldPoints, out hitInfo, distance + 0.2f, cullingLayer, Color.blue))
{
    // distance = hitInfo.distance;                    //WORKING BUT WALLS GLITCHING DUE TO HEIGHT  
    distance = hitInfo.distance - 0.2f;                               
    if (distance < defaultDistance)
    {
        var t = hitInfo.distance;
        t -= cullingMinDist;
        t /= cullingMinDist;
        currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp(cullingHeight, height, Mathf.Clamp(t, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        current_cPos = currentTargetPos + new Vector3(0, currentHeight, 0);
    }
```

and if I change the the distance to hit.Info.distance instead of hitInfo.distance -0.2f as shown above, it will just start glitching.

```
using Invector;
using UnityEngine;

public class vThirdPersonCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
#region inspector properties    

public Transform target;
[Tooltip("Lerp speed between Camera States")]
public float smoothCameraRotation = 12f;
[Tooltip("What layer will be culled")]
public LayerMask cullingLayer = 1 << 0;
[Tooltip("Debug purposes, lock the camera behind the character for better align the states")]
public bool lockCamera;

public float rightOffset = 0f;
public float defaultDistance = 2.5f;
public float height = 1.4f;
public float smoothFollow = 10f;
public float xMouseSensitivity = 3f;
public float yMouseSensitivity = 3f;
public float yMinLimit = -40f;
public float yMaxLimit = 80f;


#endregion

#region hide properties    

[HideInInspector]
public int indexList, indexLookPoint;
[HideInInspector]
public float offSetPlayerPivot;
[HideInInspector]
public string currentStateName;
[HideInInspector]
public Transform currentTarget;
[HideInInspector]
public Vector2 movementSpeed;

private Transform targetLookAt;
private Vector3 currentTargetPos;
private Vector3 lookPoint;
private Vector3 current_cPos;
private Vector3 desired_cPos;
private Camera _camera;
private float distance = 5f;
private float mouseY = 0f;
private float mouseX = 0f;
private float currentHeight;
private float cullingDistance;
private float checkHeightRadius = 0.4f;
private float clipPlaneMargin = 0f;
private float forward = -1f;
private float xMinLimit = -360f;
private float xMaxLimit = 360f;
private float cullingHeight = 0.2f;
private float cullingMinDist = 0.1f;

#endregion

void Start()
{
    Init();
}

public void Init()
{
    if (target == null)
        return;

    _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    currentTarget = target;
    currentTargetPos = new Vector3(currentTarget.position.x, currentTarget.position.y + offSetPlayerPivot, currentTarget.position.z);

    targetLookAt = new GameObject("targetLookAt").transform;
    targetLookAt.position = currentTarget.position;
    targetLookAt.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
    targetLookAt.rotation = currentTarget.rotation;

    mouseY = currentTarget.eulerAngles.x;
    mouseX = currentTarget.eulerAngles.y;

    distance = defaultDistance;
    currentHeight = height;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (target == null || targetLookAt == null) return;

    CameraMovement();
}

/// <summary>
/// Set the target for the camera
/// </summary>
/// <param name="New cursorObject"></param>
public void SetTarget(Transform newTarget)
{
    currentTarget = newTarget ? newTarget : target;
}

public void SetMainTarget(Transform newTarget)
{
    target = newTarget;
    currentTarget = newTarget;
    mouseY = currentTarget.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
    mouseX = currentTarget.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    Init();
}

/// <summary>    
/// Convert a point in the screen in a Ray for the world
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Point"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public Ray ScreenPointToRay(Vector3 Point)
{
    return this.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Point);
}

/// <summary>
/// Camera Rotation behaviour
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x"></param>
/// <param name="y"></param>
public void RotateCamera(float x, float y)
{
    // free rotation 
    mouseX += x * xMouseSensitivity;
    mouseY -= y * yMouseSensitivity;

    movementSpeed.x = x;
    movementSpeed.y = -y;
    if (!lockCamera)
    {
        mouseY = vExtensions.ClampAngle(mouseY, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
        mouseX = vExtensions.ClampAngle(mouseX, xMinLimit, xMaxLimit);
    }
    else
    {
        mouseY = currentTarget.root.localEulerAngles.x;
        mouseX = currentTarget.root.localEulerAngles.y;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Camera behaviour
/// </summary>    
void CameraMovement()
{
    if (currentTarget == null)
        return;

    distance = Mathf.Lerp(distance, defaultDistance, smoothFollow * Time.deltaTime);
    cullingDistance = Mathf.Lerp(cullingDistance, distance, Time.deltaTime);
    var camDir = (forward * targetLookAt.forward) + (rightOffset * targetLookAt.right);

    camDir = camDir.normalized;

    var targetPos = new Vector3(currentTarget.position.x, currentTarget.position.y + offSetPlayerPivot, currentTarget.position.z);
    currentTargetPos = targetPos;
    desired_cPos = targetPos + new Vector3(0, height, 0);
    current_cPos = currentTargetPos + new Vector3(0, currentHeight, 0);
    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    ClipPlanePoints planePoints = _camera.NearClipPlanePoints(current_cPos + (camDir * (distance)), clipPlaneMargin);
    ClipPlanePoints oldPoints = _camera.NearClipPlanePoints(desired_cPos + (camDir * distance), clipPlaneMargin);

    //Check if Height is not blocked 
    if (Physics.SphereCast(targetPos, checkHeightRadius, Vector3.up, out hitInfo, cullingHeight + 0.2f, cullingLayer))
    {
        var t = hitInfo.distance - 0.2f;
        t -= height;
        t /= (cullingHeight - height);
        cullingHeight = Mathf.Lerp(height, cullingHeight, Mathf.Clamp(t, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    }

    //Check if desired target position is not blocked       
    if (CullingRayCast(desired_cPos, oldPoints, out hitInfo, distance + 0.2f, cullingLayer, Color.blue))
    {
        // distance = hitInfo.distance;                    //WORKING BUT WALLS GLITCHING DUE TO HEIGHT  
        distance = hitInfo.distance - 0.2f;                               
        if (distance < defaultDistance)
        {
            var t = hitInfo.distance;
            t -= cullingMinDist;
            t /= cullingMinDist;
            currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp(cullingHeight, height, Mathf.Clamp(t, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            current_cPos = currentTargetPos + new Vector3(0, currentHeight, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentHeight = height;
    }
    //Check if target position with culling height applied is not blocked
    if (CullingRayCast(current_cPos, planePoints, out hitInfo, distance, cullingLayer, Color.cyan)) distance = Mathf.Clamp(cullingDistance, 0.0f, defaultDistance);
    var lookPoint = current_cPos + targetLookAt.forward * 2f;
    lookPoint += (targetLookAt.right * Vector3.Dot(camDir * (distance), targetLookAt.right));
    targetLookAt.position = current_cPos;

    Quaternion newRot = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
    targetLookAt.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(targetLookAt.rotation, newRot, smoothCameraRotation * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position = current_cPos + (camDir * (distance));
    var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation((lookPoint) - transform.position);

    transform.rotation = rotation;
    movementSpeed = Vector2.zero;
}

/// <summary>
/// Custom Raycast using NearClipPlanesPoints
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_to"></param>
/// <param name="from"></param>
/// <param name="hitInfo"></param>
/// <param name="distance"></param>
/// <param name="cullingLayer"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
bool CullingRayCast(Vector3 from, ClipPlanePoints _to, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float distance, LayerMask cullingLayer, Color color)
{
    bool value = false;

    if (Physics.Raycast(from, _to.LowerLeft - from, out hitInfo, distance, cullingLayer))
    {
        value = true;
        cullingDistance = hitInfo.distance;
    }

    if (Physics.Raycast(from, _to.LowerRight - from, out hitInfo, distance, cullingLayer))
    {
        value = true;
        if (cullingDistance > hitInfo.distance) cullingDistance = hitInfo.distance;
    }

    if (Physics.Raycast(from, _to.UpperLeft - from, out hitInfo, distance, cullingLayer))
    {
        value = true;
        if (cullingDistance > hitInfo.distance) cullingDistance = hitInfo.distance;
    }

    if (Physics.Raycast(from, _to.UpperRight - from, out hitInfo, distance, cullingLayer))
    {
        value = true;
        if (cullingDistance > hitInfo.distance) cullingDistance = hitInfo.distance;
    }

    return hitInfo.collider && value;
}
```

}

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/game-toolkits/third-person-controller-basic-locomotion-free-82048#description

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix it. After spending all day on it, I finally realized that the box colliders on the walls were too small. Anyway will probably look for a more simple answer from now on instead of just running to the script.